# Unknown ARP opcode (256) and hw type (256)

Tags: arp

When chcking out the ARP packets on my network, I see some values that I can't see are documented. Here are some output from debug statements:

Ether_ARP

Sender:      192.168.10.1    fc:52:8d:5f:73:35

Target:      192.168.10.102  00:00:00:00:00:00

**Format of hardware address. = 256**

Format of protocol address. = 8

Length of hardware address. = 6

Length of protocol address. = 4

**ARP opcode (command)        = 256**

Appreciate a pointer. Could not find this in docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Major egg on my face. try to remember byte order. When I use ntohs(256) I get 1...
Next time I will be more diligent before pposting. Promise